# Long time to update my changes in firebase hosting

Tags: firebase-hosting

I've been hosting my Angular2 app with Firebase.

Then every time I deploy my app on Firebase, I cannot see my changes soon, and seems it takes a long time to update my app.

Is it usual for firebase hosting not to reflect the differences of source code? Now I'm planning to upgrade my firebase plan. If anyone knows about this, I hope to know. Thanks.

Comment: *firebaser here* Changes you deploy to Firebase Hosting should be available to your users immediately. If that doesn't happen, check the [Firebase status page](https://status.firebase.google.com/) to see if there's a known outage. If the problem happens consistently and there's no outage, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/).

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your commenting. @FrankvanPuffelen